# fast double integration over a sphere

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I need to perform 5 numerical integrations over the surface of a unit sphere.

I have tried with `dblquad` but this is taking quite some time.

Here is a MRE:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate

def foo():

    f1 = lambda theta, phi: np.cos(theta)**2
    f2 = lambda theta, phi: f1(theta, phi)*np.cos(theta)**2*np.sin(theta)  
    
    ret = np.zeros(5)
    
    ret[0] = integrate.dblquad(f2, 0, 2*np.pi, 0, np.pi)[0]
    ret[1] = integrate.dblquad(f2, 0, 2*np.pi, 0, np.pi)[0]
    ret[2] = integrate.dblquad(f2, 0, 2*np.pi, 0, np.pi)[0]
    ret[3] = integrate.dblquad(f2, 0, 2*np.pi, 0, np.pi)[0]
    ret[4] = integrate.dblquad(f2, 0, 2*np.pi, 0, np.pi)[0]

    return ret
    
def main():
    tst = np.zeros((1000, 5))
    for i in range(1000):
        tst[i] = foo()
        
    
main()
```

In my machine when I do `%timeit main()` I get `21.4 s ± 126 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`

This code structure is taking a long like to perform the computations, any way to improve this?

Comment: I'm assuming these are just example functions to show that it takes a while. Correct?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71244504/reducing-redundancy-for-calculating-large-number-of-integrals-numerically/71245570#71245570. It provides a fast Numba implementation (thanks to `LowLevelCallable`) for `quad` which is similar to `dblquad`. You can also use Cython. Simple precision might also be faster if you do not care about having precise results.

Comment: Besides, you can compute `np.cos(theta) ** 2` once (otherwise it will be computed twice, certainly even in Numba). In fact, you can just compute directly `np.cos(theta) ** 4`. Actually you can even precompute `y = sin(x)` and then compute `y-2*y**3+y**5`. This means only 1 trigonometric function is computed per call rather than 3 initially. Trigonometric functions are pretty expensive so avoiding them is better.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the computation faster by using numba and jitting the `f1`/`f2` functions:

```py
import numpy as np
from numba import njit
from scipy import integrate


@njit
def f1(theta, phi):
    return np.cos(theta) ** 2


@njit
def f2(theta, phi):
    return f1(theta, phi) * np.cos(theta) ** 2 * np.sin(theta)


def foo():
    ret = np.zeros(5)

    ret[0] = integrate.dblquad(f2, 0, 2 * np.pi, 0, np.pi)[0]
    ret[1] = integrate.dblquad(f2, 0, 2 * np.pi, 0, np.pi)[0]
    ret[2] = integrate.dblquad(f2, 0, 2 * np.pi, 0, np.pi)[0]
    ret[3] = integrate.dblquad(f2, 0, 2 * np.pi, 0, np.pi)[0]
    ret[4] = integrate.dblquad(f2, 0, 2 * np.pi, 0, np.pi)[0]

    return ret


def main():
    tst = np.zeros((1000, 5))
    for i in range(1000):
        tst[i] = foo()


main()
```

---

Running it with `time` on my machine (AMD 5700x/Python 3.11):

```py
andrej@MyPC:/app$ time python3 script.py

real    0m2,204s
user    0m0,013s
sys     0m0,004s
```

---

For comparison, without the `@njit` decorator:

```
andrej@MyPC:/app$ time python3 script.py

real    0m13,505s
user    0m0,014s
sys     0m0,004s
```

Comment: This is perfect. I should look more into these libraries! With this version of the code I get: `1.6 s ± 24.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)` which is ~13.5x faster